# How to change wave speed in a-frame-extras - Ocean?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am using frame extras to create an ocean

https://webvr.donmccurdy.com/water/

The ocean is working great but I would like to adjust the speed of the waves and the documentation seems to suggest this is possible using either 'speed' or 'speedVariance'. When I change these it does not seem to effect it however.

I include the following script

https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js

And then try the below to no avail - all the other parameters work fine;

```
<a-ocean 
    width=“50” 
    depth=“50" 
    density=“10”  
    color=“#d9d0ae ”  
    position=“0 0 0” 
    opacity=“1"
    speed=“0.1”
    speedVariance=“0.2">
 </a-ocean>
```

Is there a minimum speed perhaps? But even if I put it up to 10 it does not change. Also, is it possible to stop the animation all together?

Thanks for any help

Comment: When I change the speed and speedVariance in the a-frame inspector it works fine - it just does not respond to me specifying it in the html

Comment: Can you post a demo, on Codepen or Glitch or something? I'm not sure but it looks like there may be "smart quotes" sneaking into your HTML.

Comment: Hi Don, thanks for getting back. I have an example here on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/91joxqkr/

Comment: Oops, yes it's a bug. I've [filed an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/issues/194). In the meantime you can use the component version to work around it: `<a-entity ocean="speed: 0.1"></a-entity>`.

Comment: Ok thanks, thats a good way round it. There is something strange going on with the rotation with that approach though. I see that the ocean tag gets rotated -90 on the x axis by default - that doesn't happen doing it this way but when I add that rule in it ignores it - you can see on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/91joxqkr/2/

Comment: Yeah, the default rotation is only changed when using the primitive version. Feel free to open an issue on Github, that can probably be fixed too.

Comment: Ok thank you. The ocean add on is great by the way.